# Reconnect socket connection when browser refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have a React and Node app that uses a socket to communicated. This works fine, until I refresh the browser. I read that the socket gets disconnected when you leave the page or refresh - ok.

I need to reconnect or create a new connect upon refresh. How do I do this?

On the client side I have:

```
let socket = openSocket(window.location.href);
...

if(socket.disconnected) { //on refresh this is true
        socket = openSocket(window.location.href);
        socket.open(); //this never seems to connect.
}

socket.on(id, msg => { //on refresh this is disconnected
    //do stuff
}
```

My backend is typical node code:

```
const socket_io    = require( "socket.io" );

let app = express();
var io = socket_io();
app.io = io;

io.on( "connection", function( socket )
{
    console.log( "A user connected" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the following:

```
let socket = openSocket(window.location.href);
```

Depending where you are in the app, this could be https://example.org/login, instead of https://example.org.

My solution is

```
let socket = openSocket(window.location.origin);
```